# I have a datetimepicker, if a validation fails set the date back to older date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have 2 datetime pickers and in the value changed event of dtp1  I am validating if dtp1 > dtp2 and if yes, I am doing some thing. If the above condition is true I want to set the date in dtp1 to back what it was earlier.Which event do I have to use to achieve this.  I searched over the internet but couldn't find any relevant solution.Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is my code below

```
   private void dtp1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                    
    if (dtp1.Value > dtp2.Value)
       {
        MessageBox.Show("dtp1 cannot be greater than dtp2");
        Button1.Enabled = false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to set it back then you'll have to use a DateTime variable so you know what the previous value was.  It is risky, that previous value might be bad as well and then you'll get stuck in an endless loop of message boxes.  Consider that it isn't actually necessary, you are already disabling Button1 so they can't use the invalid date anyway.  Just don't forget to re-enable it when the value is good.

Comment: Thanks for your response @HansPassant. I just wanted to see if there is any event that I could place this validation in instead of value changed event. I agree that using variables would cause other issues.